# compute ratio of scaling polygon to get given area of polygon

Tags: c++, math

I have a set of points for a polygon. I can get the area of it.

for examples I have polygon.Area() = 1500;

now, I need to make that polygon that gives area 1350, how to scale ratio value of it.
I try to get it scaling by bounding box ratio. but it does not work.
I try this way. but answer is not correct.

I Get a Bounding box of the polygon ( min point and max point) of the box.

```
    float OldArea = 1500.0f;
    float newArea = 1350.0f;
    
    Vec2 Min_Point =  polygon.Min();
    Vec2 Max_Point = polygon.Max();
    
    float SizeX = Min_Point.SizeX(Max_Point);// it give Length of X of Bounding Box (x2-x1)
    float SizeY = Min_Point.SizeY(Max_Point);//it give Length of Y of Bounding Box (y2-y1)
    
    float ratio  = SizeX/SizeY;
    
        float aa = sqrt(NewArea/ ratio); // get first Length
        float bb =  NewArea/aa;  // ge4t second length
        float Scale_Ratio = (bb/SizeY ); // get scale ratio // but this is not correct.
```

Please someone help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scale_Ratio = Math.sqrt(newArea/oldArea)

That's because the ratio will be applied to the area twice -- once when you multiply the width, and once when you multiply the height, so the ratio of scaled areas is the square of the ratio applied to each dimension.